# A Compile-time templated event system and dispatch manager

Tags: c++, event-handling, c++20

### Problem

I would like to make an efficient, extensible, and potentially asynchronous parallelizable event system using modern features in C++20.

### My solution

I've constructed a templated event struct by category and group:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

namespace System::Event {
enum class Type {
    Group = 0,
    Tick, Update, Render, Terminate,
    Connect, Disconnect,
    Move, Close, Resize, Refresh, Focus, Defocus, Maximize, Minimize, Restore,
    Press, Release, Type,
    Scroll,
};

enum class Group {
    Undefined   = 0,
    Instance    = Numerics::Bit(0), // 1
    Monitor     = Numerics::Bit(1), // 2
    Window      = Numerics::Bit(2), // 4
    Input       = Numerics::Bit(3),
    Keyboard    = Numerics::Bit(4),
    Mouse       = Numerics::Bit(5),
    Controller  = Numerics::Bit(6),
    Button      = Numerics::Bit(7),
};
Structure::Concept::Tag bitmask(System::Event::Group);
}
```

Here the group acts as a type-safe bitmask with overloaded operators. (Usage below)

The base event class only contains a status member variable (used, unused, lost, etc).

```cpp
namespace System::Event {
template<Type T, Group G>
struct Event {
    System::Structure::Status::Event status;
};
}
```

There are various implementations of events, but here is a simple Window Close Event:

```cpp
namespace System::Event::Window {
    struct Close : public Event <Type::Close, Group::Instance + Group::Window> {
       Close() : Event({System::Structure::Status::Event::Unused}) {}
       class Manager;
    };
}
```

Now, I want a method to dispatch a `Window::Close event`.

```cpp
namespace System::Event::Window {
    class Close::Manager {
        private:
            using Callback = Structure::Callback<System::Event::Window::Close &>; // std::function<>
        public:
            void listen(Callback callback) {
                m_Callbacks.push_back(callback);
            }
            void deafen(Callback callback) {
                m_Callbacks.erase(std::remove_if(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(m_Callbacks), std::end(m_Callbacks), [&callback](const Callback & other) {
                    return callback.target<Callback>() == other.target<Callback>();
                }));
            }
            void queue(Window::Close & event) {
                m_Event = event;
            }
            void latest() {
                std::for_each(std::begin(m_Callbacks), std::end(m_Callbacks), [&](const Callback & callback) {
                    callback(m_Event);
                });
            }
         private:
            std::vector<Callback> m_Callbacks;
            Window::Close m_Event;
    };
}
```

### Usage

This is an example unit test. (Not final, demonstrates usage)

```cpp
    auto callback = [](System::Event::Window::Close & event) {
        EXPECT_TRUE(event.status == System::Structure::Status::Event::Unused);
        event.status = System::Structure::Status::Event::Used;
    };
    System::Event::Window::Close::Manager manager;
    manager.listen(callback);
    manager.latest();
    System::Event::Window::Close event;
    manager.queue(event);
    manager.deafen(callback);
    manager.latest();
    manager.listen(callback);
    manager.latest();
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRC8r6ADJ5amAHLOAEaYxFwArACcpAAOqEKE5rR2ji5uMXEJdN6%2BAU7BoZyRRpgmZnQMBMzEBMnOrrzGmKaJFVUE2f5BIeFRQpXVtakN/e0%2BnXndhREAlEaoDsTIHFI6AMw%2ByI5YANSaqzZswCSECE572JoyAIJrG1uYu/totEvRBELnlzfa6y/3jzZMOImg4yrRPtdbn8HDs9jYqA4XmC2BDvr9NjCHnCAG5NIjEVFfKEY2H7ZhCETVAB0CEJ11ozCcmCE0WYS22uRCeGQQl2AHZ9NdtsLts8%2BkDosRtoj4sBfOhtj4CNtdIQIDK8HLMAqldtxNN%2BYKriKTdtiJgCAtaNtOAC4Xq9kaTZo%2BQARIlur4MpkstkPCrEBymBZYgVfE3e5ms9l2F6YN6G8Om4V9QOmbYAFWYwETntWTuTuyFhYImCc0VUpYBm3JvIuqwuxeTz1eyuwtGcIWYYMerrNmAAjg48OahBBsNtMAaXQXCyK%2BugQCA8EIAPpWZyr7Fw%2Bv12dz7YLpfPXHVPCBdirog70iHgiLkCIrDEVgATx8wCvr%2BimB3nwbjpJged4PkqmDAMQKL7Eej7WCEb4fl%2BP5/gBqH7s6eb7i67qQk22yluWla/k8qgUtsohVIyFohKiJoOPE6jbAcrCsIEbIANa9iBS4IkiiQ4qgeAKhAFGQUypZSjoABs0z/ka2FEvSVG%2BuyAZBpa5pLrGraJnhBEVt2WIkbWma0SKLbxsqqoEE45KcXsfbmkOI7MhAGb4dOYZ4Sa7adpBYJwhmclAaaM4hXOgSELZQjsRABCyd5IoKYlwoALTnNxIBCFRq7knCanBppIDaZZS5ZsAwV4Qp%2BYejhNzXPpREAgVGkcMVdCtku1nRZx2DsEy9ComKpbiJK2x9WWVjKqgP7%2BSQuzaFJ2zjv1U3bKwCBCLeE0DcqxCbZ5%2B70R%2BmZcTBT7we%2B6hIZgV47qtg1oSF5oadafTdtyq4sH092TY92AQO9ZjIF95IEIF5wQBtQjTotd4fSD33g/sQUNhA%2B0w7JNWQp6DVlgZVb5QQaatVpHWlSA3V2eND3I42VzDRKUo7Wt0nbDNXb4gtUkOctLP0Nz62bdttNmgdunGiK0NcdLbMY4BeEvVaQsfNjNy41cjWGc1xPqSGZNxm8XVRdT/N018jOjczosc3Nkl6HzovQyLf17eLYV4cdjHubz51wS%2BV2fgQ363cjNhm5VkvCkrxBvZUwOgz9%2BwR2jQOfUjENo9Dnk2PDCcZyjkMY9MWPyRrWuE/sLX6%2B1hsEMbNmm7TQ10OKVs067gu29280GLzK2d2zzsd7tYswxLJqy6sfayw78tqyaMfWtDCvq3VFdGTY1dFSVRuUybMUj1NLe0G3Y1m%2Bzs095JYQTgPo/DxfxcTyKXs5j70%2BZRdAeIcHP53cnZuT1FYWmVmnRGYNfq7UhuAxOYdUYA2zrsW%2Bed06QMLmjYupdapfA3jrEmNdd7133o3Q%2BKd6aW3PqLNm3cuaaFvv3C%2BQ9hZHwFs/D2UcVYy02sgic899xLxVqvZKmt8ZNSJgQne5M95UzIUAihrcRpUM7rQ%2BaqVHad0fqLdhXlOGCNligqGPC5YHWEeXMR2sJF6ykXXBuPVWHm2uJQ62g84aqKlOlT%2B99WZwy0Z3HR%2B4p4zx4eo/hz1QGxyEWrEReCrGFTakQuxTdXYnzPlKQIqB7CX05r3BsGiH4sKfu7XRdEGLvzOveJc38ELXT/qHKBx9gF6IiXHBGcDM6IOMXDdheSZBmPXhYyuW9dbxINp1Eh9jyEW0UUzbYGSsnuMePWPs3iBZ%2BNHgE8Jr1lpTz4cUmwLpc5GN5A5Xmxd%2Bm4MGZvbeCTpHENkb1eR0zT5KPSZk1g2S7a9kYU7Qp2jikCJaVw05n8wk4wGYRSxVcRmk1ruMh5DjUmvLme8z5187ReIvustamyQHbOOQCMeOdDk7OMdPM5pjonmMhUMm5YyKYIqmU4mZ7d5kfMWfaVZypsVsIBSFN%2Bp1faVNgs%2BGpQcQ4APDk8heIpBGwILjYBBBLQnu3JZ/PpVK6pemUtGf0r5xROCXHSkArRLQnJKSKDcThRSkV5AAJURGYJkL9kwAElaAJDYHgAAXtqLiMhSDhRFAzMw2JDLoEDSlbY7qJKBjeNqSNnCTQZhCE4Hw4bE1zgCCxPAVA8AJpCtVfcVqbUmWwLiAWHC5wCA7CIBUvMA1BuFMIAtUa7VllQLiCNTbtgAFkVwGSWN2qN2BiDEBIK2zhRaQolprGRUd47JIWuTDWrAeb5T%2BszYWPwdBMBbuFNO8FikriRhUnqg1S5y2s10bO21mYQ4uu2AAcXHQ4aIm6QoZm5OxW8AhojoEMredt/tbwpuIGmhkpZ91MToL4Uwt5XQrmeHBgg0He2dr3UxVgcRMPtviL6oDmAqCjgQLeAAYqgZA9EENEco9RvtzBxB4DTQRvtPhmM%2Btw8yfEe6QqiFHFtbY7b2DkkwxmEO0GmDjpYomw99Uri3pMi%2B%2BY76q0ilXURsYCoD3qug%2B696cZnSf05MQbkQgG4QBkLMbYAB6GzNoQroY9VzIzfYTNmYs5wazdntjaBCgAdR8OgVAAB3ZMvN3M8gs9obz9nuAhXddEUEhYIt%2BQ8yQiAqxZghQANKYFfBkqo2mdNubS1FjL3Bst4XQ/RB44XjNlfMxlsIVXOGxmJvYdgUouKRaa9ZCAMloO6FBEQa0oUGtMlM%2BV/rfJWtyaNTCwhdyyrZjmQfWKDB9UEUvRW4hym33YNwqImlxFFUPozLefb76n1mRTDC8au3H0mk2xek1i2iqmvojttaQN6Krwwu6TVx7T26u2C97bIAr30CXIF6woXH2pnUlhnD2wQDbCSxebkD3Wb7HvT%2BLS2GRCXdfdEJc%2BnKiGYMM%2BknMOgvw4ymp5MNhCeYAgAaNHUOCAQBnODssC3JFtU%2B01znS4a21fQNhQ6Ii5xzt5L2tQ2YaIyoPZhEKsvkciCXPLhkwAQhPZFJKPAYbSwgB7aUk6zFWIcS4vz6xCS2BW%2BQOxfKW2%2BeQ927TuHIWCco%2BkpHOcGPWDclN1Gk02JBIKiD%2BKWgEBLdsSd6KB38f2JS9D4WJwq448cSEFSJLQgECrmTxAFgLFk%2BHaTSljWwFhTh6EtsLAzAqBWFj0n63JfHcp/18BDPWenc567CIQGwrzROAw6uXNQ%2BHxAhBGCJcrJiCrhlIOW8MFgjAB8BAHvre%2B/WZgh4Tfmft/sRhreeh%2BhFrt%2BT/Q10xfFFMSP13AgCAQip4r9X2VQLL8cSpP0XXYde/O5ozThqp9ioBP4hA/5VB/5wgAGQzl7v4A4lz/bV7S7V614KhDiYAOCs6w7Bbe7FQs6CyYC7av4IEigZ6c5cTEGNLoSV51Tv7oHrSGR9Bs5d4HgwQ0AL6YBsgICT5LjT5Uaz4gDz6L6nzL6ZRr4b5b6l7Z677Cr77SEd4n7ILn48xhA37DT34yEJ5sxf5O6kFkGmh6GxQUEkHIFkGS7mEHioHJiG7G4cBm7zjCq4imAkAwFH4ZSKHJ6qy0HJi4GhY%2B4iDbCmE0E9pyYiJfC6i2Qb4GHCjMCgioCJ7aH2Sfxn7X4QC86Gru5TSe54GBFYhwzUH0CxGmi1ghBc5FEEBUi/YnIgFg6u5ZHGpC7fbQ4gBi51rwGFiVHVHxz0RcSZG26jJvbdhfbZGtEtoS7K78iA77gDFjHEL%2BH4HM44Za4K665Si2Q65K77ibGK7EBUhR6lgx7GGdHCi7HrEHHMFc6nH1GvYi4gCLH5GTi7ZWHnEQGYHYEQCVE3FvH7EN5N7HFH4/FrEQFEQsHAlbH7GHHN4nGvEglQlXFs5WGCIaplyuhSCzCsDSBhDyCuCyDyCoDSAHJ6BU5CDzCLAFGrCcDyD1z4klykDsQgCRBUhSQyB8h8jcCrBSTcARARCLQyBSQqDSDcC4nSByCkCElSDyDmYBq0lyCzBwCwAwCIAoCoDlh4BdbkCUBoDqldYoCqDqCcDaAyABp5qsASTmYQCBBinyCRQMjECvjSDUmkA6m7QADytAb4NppAWAmxwA7A3p%2BA5ozQuI5m%2BJpAAhoIyw4pYEWJ4ZQegQkEDpdgWA3pxMzGTpGJfAdAjAJeHAPA2ZggIgEg3pSg2gKgagGgfcegKg545mkAswM0YIYZqUC4DkWgJJegxp0pJQeIiQlg1ggwrgnAEZ1gHQuQ%2BQygsQ8QYIQ5U5GQYI45XQBQxQpQLQIwc5I5jQzQ5QIwS5EwK570Aw9gdQygR5owOQy5XAswZJCwSw15QpUgOJpAeJ4pkp4gAAHFJKlNyaWoxEaVSDIIBXzPgHQj8COTBrqXrmsDFkxNWboDSTafSc/swM%2BJQLMIydoB%2BVSKsGEMaVJNoFMHyGyZwIKXGSKaQIamEAGq%2BQSdINKSALKUhaQIqSqfMAQElqhhQLflBaEOWdqIQCQMoPwLmWwPmYKSJS2iWeGSFpBKTlINSZidiaKeGZKW6aCJxezFQHqF%2BT%2BdwH%2BTmABUBTIMtHYLxQtKsDFohXSbMChWhWzo%2BRRVRTRd6ZKQxUxTZQyW4EBasHydoGEFJLhSaXyL5VyY%2BasCpW%2BfRaQHKRiUpVINoJFXRVKTFUhbMKePEBYNwEAA%3D%3D)

### Comments/Questions

1. This method will produce a large amount of redundant code; I'd like to make the `Manager` class a template specialization at some point.
2. This will require each type of event to have a manager. How can I consolidate all Window events into one manager without impacting performance or using runtime polymorphism?
3. I will migrate to use `std::ranges` after `clang` supports it.
4. At some point, I'd like to additionally include execution policies in the dispatch methods, I have yet to determine the best choices.
5. `queue` will eventually involve a stack of stored events so that I can determine how to interpolate which events matter if the system is lagging or otherwise. For example if there is a Mouse move from (1,1) to (180,180), with a (1,1) delta, it'd be scaled to frame-rates instead of rendering every delta.
6. I understand this is not the intended use of `namespace` or `class` namespaces, it is a personal preference.
7. This is not the best design; I'm exploring, please be critical of all flaws!
8. Owning [repository](https://github.com/Maelkevejen/Andromeda), for the curious. I am continuing to change the design since this post, however.

### Notes

I am very intentionally avoiding runtime polymorphism.